# How old were the War Doctor, Nine and Ten when they regenerated, and how certain are we of these ages?

Tags: doctor-who

We know Eleven lived more than a thousand years total (three hundred at least, before Trenzalore, and around 900 in Trenzalore, if I remember well). Do we have enough information to estimate how long Nine and Ten lived? 
Since the Doctor often rounds the number or fudge it, I'd like to know the range in years, minimum and maximum total lifespan for each, that'd match the available information, not just best guess.

Comment: I've edited my question, to explain that in fact here I'm not as interested in their ages at a given point as much as I want to know how long each incarnation might have had to live.

Comment: But knowing the approximate ages of each incarnation gives you the information for how long each one was incarnate

Comment: Only if you know the approximate age upon regeneration. We know Nine is 900 years old at some point, but when did he regenerate? RTD said he would have been around for quite some time before Rose. Also, the ages reported by Ten don't quite add up. How old was he when he started? 900? 903? How old was the Doctor at the moment of each regeneration, and how sure are we of this? That would be the equivalent question, in fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Doctor's Age](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Doctor's_age) article on the TARDIS wikia gives the following information about the age of the War Doctor:

> WAR DOCTOR
>   The Last Great Time War, in which the War Doctor fought, lasted not less than 400 years of linear time, although at the time of his experiences in the Tantalus Spiral, which led him to decide the war could go on "no more", this incarnation's age was a hundred years or more. (PROSE: Engines of War) Shortly before the end of his life, the War Doctor said he was 400 years younger than the Eleventh Doctor when he gave his age as "twelve hundred or something", making him somewhere between 800 and 900 years old. (TV: The Day of the Doctor)

So based on the last line, the War Doctor could have been anywhere from 801 to 899 years old in The Day of the Doctor, when he regenerated into the Ninth. Note that although there's a popular fan theory that in the first episode "Rose" the Ninth Doctor was freshly regenerated, Russell T. Davies, who wrote that episode and was the showrunner at the time, has said he imagined Nine to have been around for quite some time when we saw him in "Rose" (see the last part of my answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/103602/22250) for a quote).

The article goes on to say the following about the ages of Nine and Ten:

> NINTH DOCTOR
>   The Ninth Doctor claimed "900 years of time and space". Immediately after he made this comment, Rose asked, "When you say 900 years?—" and he responded, "That's my age." (TV: Aliens of London) Later, when Rose appeared to wander off, he mentioned to a cat that the only thing left to surprise him after "900 years of phone box travel" was whenever he met someone who got the "don't wander off thing". When Rose asked him about his name, saying "Don't you ever get tired of 'Doctor'? Doctor Who?" He responded, "Nine centuries in, I'm coping." (TV: The Empty Child)
>
> TENTH DOCTOR
>   The Tenth Doctor said he was 903 years old while attempting to rescue the Titanic. (TV: Voyage of the Damned) Prior to the Titanic incident, he claimed to have spent at least 33 months searching for Martha Jones in deep space (TV: The Infinite Quest), and several months living in various time periods on Earth (PROSE: The Stone Rose, TV: Human Nature / The Family of Blood, Blink) and inside the Valiant during the so-called Year That Never Was. (TV: Last of the Time Lords) He again claimed 903 during an adventure with Donna Noble. (AUDIO: The Nemonite Invasion) In a later adventure in Nevada, he said 900 again, suggesting he was approximating. (TV: Dreamland) While confronting a rabbit in Elizabethan England he briefly believed to be a Zygon in disguise, he said he was 904 years old. (TV: The Day of the Doctor) Just prior to regenerating, he gave his age as 906, suggesting that several years had passed for the Doctor after his travels with Donna Noble. (TV: The End of Time)

Based on these two, the Ninth Doctor could have been 900, 901, 902, or potentially even 903 when he regenerated into the Tenth, although I doubt he was as old as 903 because that would mean Ten's travels with both Rose and Martha lasted less than a subjective year for him (in fact, given that he gave his age as 900 in the first season and 903 in "Voyage of the Damned" which was the Christmas special after the end of the third season, we can guess that each of the first three seasons represented roughly a year in his life, in which case Nine was probably 900 or 901 when he regenerated into Ten).

Still, it would be consistent with these dates for the Ninth Doctor to have been around for as large a time as 801 years to 903 years, or for as little a time as under one year (if he regenerated just before "Rose" at age 899, and he was still 900 years old when he regenerated into Ten). For Ten, it seems the max would be 900-906, the min would be 903-906. So, my answer would be:

**Nine: maximum 102 years, minimum under 1 year.**

**Ten: maximum 6 years, minimum 3 years.**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Only one point, I believe Wikia's article is a bit confusing. I'd think the Doctor's rounding down or outright lying since Seven is said to be over 950 years old before regenerating. I believe he  had 'reset' his counter at some point, so the War Doctor and Eleven share a common reference point, knowing both are quite older than they admit. But since this reset must have happened before Nine, your calculations would be correct. It's possible he's also 'discounting' the Year That Never Was.

Comment: @confusedwhovian - Yes, fans have a number of ideas about how to reconcile Seven claiming to be 953 with Nine claiming to be 900...one popular theory is that he switched from counting the years since his birth to counting the years since he started traveling in the TARDIS, although this has problems too since in "The Doctor's Wife" the TARDIS-in-human-form says they've been traveling together 700 years.

Comment: My personal explanation: maybe through most of the classic series the Doctor had been giving his age in Gallifreyan years (except in specific cases where he explicitly said he was translating his age into Earth years, like the Second Doctor saying he was about 450 "if we count in Earth terms" in "Tomb of the Cybermen"), and then at some point after the Seventh Doctor, he switched to giving his age in Earth years, which were slightly longer.

Comment: Well, the TARDIS may be counting only subjective time while in the Vortex...

Comment: I knew roughly the amount of time each lived, but I didn't know the upper bounds, in fact. Knowing that Nine may have been around for 100 years, completely alone, gives a whole new perspective on his character. Also, the very short lifespan of Ten also throws into relief the drama of his trajectory.